# Detect end of event time session window (Apache Flink Java)

Tags: java, apache-flink, streaming-analytics

Assuming all events arrive on time and no lateness is allowed, how do I do some processing only when the session window has ended? I.e. the watermark has passed (`lastEventInWindowTimestamp + inactivityGap`).
I couldn't find any API method that is called when this happens. Can I implement this logic using a custom `ProcessWindowFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `ProcessWindowFunction` serves exactly this purpose. Such a function is called when the window is complete, and is passed (among other things) an Iterable containing the stream elements that have been assigned to the window. In the case of a session window, the `ProcessWindowFunction` isn't called until after the period of inactivity has passed.

Update: How can you report both the start and end timestamps for each session window?

I will assume that you can extract the timestamp for each event from the event itself. Then, if you are using a `ProcessWindowFunction`, you can iterate over the events in the window and determine the min and max timestamps for the events in the session -- these will be the start and end timestamps.

If, on the other hand, you would rather use a reduce function that incrementally computes the window results, you can work with tuples that track the (min, max) timestamps for each window.

Comment: What if I want to emit both the start timestamp and the end timestamp of the session window? I currently am using a custom trigger to trigger ProcessWindowFunction, but I can't detect the window end this way. I don't see a way where I can detect both.

Comment: To clarify: my custom trigger outputs "window started @ timestamp" after the actual window is bigger than a MIN_WINDOW_SIZE (i.e. lastEventTimestamp - firstEventTimestamp > MIN_WINDOW_SIZE). I want to also output "window stopped @ timestamp" when the session is finished.

Comment: Reply to Update: That won't get me the timestamp when the window ends, right? A new event might change this value. I would like to only emit the "window end" message when the session window is closed and no further events can be added to that window(i.e. watermark passes windowEnd + inactivityPeriod). Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier.

Comment: Normally the ProcessWindowFunction isn't called until after the watermark passes the window end, which includes the gap in the case of a session window. If there is no allowed lateness, the ProcessWindowFunction will only be called once; no further events will be added. Does your custom Trigger FIRE the window multiple times?

Comment: Correct, my custom Trigger fires on every element if lastEventTimestamp - firstEventTimestamp > MIN_WINDOW_SIZE. This makes it fire for every subsequent event after the above condition. This is wrong, I want to make it so that it only fires once when the above condition happens and once when the session window is closed.

Comment: It seems that your question is really about how to implement session windows where the active part of the session has some minimum duration. That's rather a different question than the one you've asked above, and it's a question I'm not prepared to answer. However, I believe doing this correctly requires more than a custom trigger, as it seems to me you have to somehow convince the MergingWindowAssigner to sometimes merge sessions that are farther apart than the gap (which it normally will not do).